# How can a service made accessible as an administrative tool in cq5

Tags: user-interface, adobe, aem

**What I want to achieve**
I want to evaluate which template and which component is used on which page and how often.
This functionality should allow dynamic evaluation.
What does that mean?
I want to be able to focus on special template or components and to select these easily from a graphical user interface.
As this functionality has clearly administrative purpose (to evaluate templates and componets before migrating to a new cq version) it should not be created as a specific page.
Thus I want to create an *administrative tool*, which can be installed separately.
Coding the functionality and creating a separate package is no problem for me, but I do not have any idea how to create an administrative tool to provide a fitting user interface.

**My Question**

How can I create an administrative tool in cq5?
Or more specific: How can I create a service with a graphical user interface, which is accessible as an administrative tool?

(a possible example for a tools graphical user interface, which I am thinking of, is the Blueprint Control Center accessible via 127.0.0.1:4502/etc/blueprints.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could actually accomplish what you need using the Bulk Editor tool, located in Tools > Importers. It allows you to query your AEM/CQ instance based on property-based criteria and content types. You would be able to, for example, search for all pages with jcr:template set to a given template type. The tool produces a graphical table with the search results, which you can export to TSV.

One thing to note, though. The tool is buggy. I've had to fix some things, especially when it comes to using the (hidden by default) import from TSV feature. In terms of querying it works ok. You just occasionally have to hit the search button a few times before it works. I'm not sure why.

You could create this administration tool yourself, but see if the Bulk Editor will get you where you need. Could be quite a bit less work.